# Running Google Chrome updates from a centralized location

Tags: windows, wsus, google-chrome

We are trying to roll out Google Chrome as out enterprise browser. Does anyone know of a solution that allows for Google Chrome to be updated from a centralized location? For example, maybe through WSUS or any other ways of doing it? Any suggestions or solutions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look here: http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146164

That gives you information on configuring GPOs to disable the built-in auto-updating feature of Chrome, etc.

Then take a look here: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/chromebrowser.html

That is the "Chrome for Business" page. There is a link on that page to an MSI installer for Chrome.  We enterprise administrators and wielders of GPOs love MSI installers, as they can be pushed out at will and controlled from a centralized location.

Comment: That solves the push but Chrome updates every few days or so in the background which is fine when 10-15 browsers are doing it but it just makes more sense to have a centralized location managing updates when 3000 browsers have to be updated constantly.

Comment: Hence why I posted the link of how to configure Chrome's auto-updating behavior and frequency via GPO.  If you still want Chrome to update from Google, but to just do it less frequently, you can configure that. If you want Chrome to only update from your server and approved updates, then turn off its auto-updating feature completely via GPO, and push updated MSIs from your distribution share, with GPO or SCCM or whatever.

Comment: So that would require i download an MSI every so often and push it? Are the MSI's truly updated? How does Chrome work? Is it a bare MSI and once downloaded it updates? If so then the MSI I download will not change. I would assume they update it periodically but not with every update which puts me at the mercy of potential security vulnerabilities. Unless they repackage MSIs for every security patch that they dish out every few weeks. Do you have any more information on that?

Comment: I would say that yes, you will be at the mercy of how often Google updates their MSI. But that's probably pretty often. I love Google Chrome, but they're probably not as enterprise-minded as we would like for them to be, and their integration with AD/WSUS/SCCM is... well, workable, but not stellar. Chrome uses the open-source "Omaha"  system for auto-updating itself. But I don't think you can reconfigure that URL to point to your own Omaha server, etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your information. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

EminentWare / SolarWinds patch manager is a great method for centrally managing and deploying third party updates. It injects updates and full installs into the wsus scheme. It includes Chrome update, among others.

http://www.eminentware.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can get it approved by your admin( if you're the admin, great job) I HIGHLY recommend using Ninite. It's [PRO version](https://ninite.com/pro?utm_campaign=navpro&utm_source=ninite&utm_medium=link) integrates with multiple RMM tools, if you're into that. It also has MSI versions, and an /updateonly switch which allows you to use one installer over and over again to ensure things like Flash and Reader stay up to date as well.

Seriously, a very awesome tool that compliments WSUS very well.